# MySQL - where clause based on same table records

Tags: mysql

I have the following `Registration` table

```
| ID | PersonID | CheckInDate |
```

and the simple query:

```
SELECT ID
     , PersonID 
     , CheckInDate  
  FROM Registration 
 WHERE CheckInDate >= '2018-06-01' 
   AND CheckInDate  < '2018-07-01'
```

`

***how to get all registrations from that set where there exists previous registration less then 30 days?***

So, for each registration, I have to check if there exists previous registration **for the same person** (for the same PersonID) .

Can I solve this problem using a single query?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"Can I solve this problem using a single query?"* Yes. Please read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Andreas, show me that query

Comment: @Paramore Are you giving me orders now? Don't you think improving the quality of your question would be better?

Comment: Andreas , just show me the query if you have

Comment: I don't care about down-vote, I'm just looking for the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT ID, PersonID, CheckInDate
  FROM Registration r1
  WHERE CheckInDate>='2018-06-01'
    AND CheckInDate< '2018-07-01'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Registration r2 
      WHERE r1.PersonID = r2.PersonID
        AND r1.CheckInDate > r2.CheckInDate
        AND datediff(r1.CheckInDate, r2.CheckInDate) < 30)
```

Comment: *"where there exists **previous** registration **less then** 30 days?"* So, `> 0` (previous) and `< 30`. And maybe flip arguments?

Comment: @Sianur, can I get `max(r2.CheckInDate)` from that query?

Comment: @Paramore, no, here the check is only for existence.

Comment: @Sianur, Is there a way to do that using single query? Maybe I should join the results again on registration table